# Vuex — как в action получить доступ к mutation из модуля c приватным namespace?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Из модуля products пробую получить доступ к mutations из модуля cart.
Этот вариант не срабатывает

```
addToCart({commit,state}, data) {
    commit('cart/ADD_TO_CARD', data)
},
```

Как это сделать корректно?

Comment: `this.commit('cart/ADD_TO_CARD', data)` или `commit('ADD_TO_CARD', data)` в зависимости от тго, где этот кусок кода находится

Comment: первое что приходит в голову - импортировать store и вызвать `store.commit('cart/ADD_TO_CARD', data)`

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, спасибо. Самый удобный вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить два варианта:

#### 1) Работа с хранилищем напрямую

В модуле products:

```
import store from 'путь к хранилищу' // берет экземпляр хранилища, не делает копию

    addToCart({commit, state}, data) {
        store.commit('cart/ADD_TO_CARD', data)
    },
```

#### 2) Добавить опцию {root: true}

```
commit('cart/ADD_TO_CARD', data, {root: true})
```

по такому же принципу работает и dispatch:

```
dispatch('notification/show', data, {root: true})
```

Comment: Спасибо. Вариант с {root: true} тоже впролне рабочий.

Comment: store же вписывается при подключении к вьюхе и доступен в компонентах через `this.$store`. не надо его везде подключать. и переименуйте что-ли `stroe`)

Comment: В компонентах он доступен, но в самом модуле через `this.$store` нет. Когда импортируешь то берешь экземпляр, не создается копии, это вполне нормальная практика.